# What pattern can I use to write CRUD functionality?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, console

I am writing a console application. CRUD functionality.I would like to try to apply the pattern. Is it possible to apply a "state" pattern? In the `AddCustomer` () method at the end, the call to the `InputMenu` () method, I do not think that this is correct. I would like to remake the "InputMenu", is it possible to apply the state pattern? Can I get rid of the switch case this way?

```
 public class DataFunction
    {

        readonly DataContext _dataContext = new DataContext();
        public DataFunction()
        {

        }

        public void AddCustomer()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Input Name");
            string _name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Input Adress");
            string _adress = Console.ReadLine();

            _dataContext.Customers.Add(
                new Customer
                {
                    Name = _name,
                    Adress = _adress
                });
            _dataContext.SaveChanges();

            InputMenu();
        }

        public void ShowAllCustomers()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("All customers in database");
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (var customer in _dataContext.Customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID - {0} Name - {1}, Adress - {2}", customer.CustomerId, customer.Name, customer.Adress);
            }
            InputMenu();
        }

        public void ShowAllCustomersForRemoveMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("All customers in database");
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (var customer in _dataContext.Customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID - {0} Name - {1}, Adress - {2}", customer.CustomerId, customer.Name, customer.Adress);
            }

        }


        public void RemoveCustomer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            ShowAllCustomersForRemoveMethod();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number to delete the user");
            Console.WriteLine();
            int _id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();

            Customer customer = _dataContext.Customers.Find(_id);
            _dataContext.Customers.Remove(customer);
            _dataContext.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine();
            InputMenu();
        }

        public void InputMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Add Customer? --- 1, Remove customer? --- 2, Show All Customer? --- 3");
            string _value = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (_value)
            {
                case "1":
                    AddCustomer();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    RemoveCustomer();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    ShowAllCustomers();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You clicked an unknown letter");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataFunction dataFunction = new DataFunction();
        dataFunction.InputMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code of the remaining methods as well?

Comment: I’ve voted to close this until the rest of the code is in the question.

Comment: I added all the code

Comment: There is one thing about your question I don't like. You are specifically requesting for a rewrite of the code to introduce the _state pattern_. This is a site for reviewing code, not for implementing patterns for you, I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me, I ask if this can be done in this case? Apply State pattern? I implement everything myself

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @Gefest, sorry for misleading comment. I misunderstood you in the way that i thought some nicely written code needed, and that the question not necessarily related to state pattern. Not sure, but may be the state one doesn't fit 100% because  next state is always same. I think that `visitor` pattern could be ok, as given in the second answer to your other question. And yes, state pattern CAN be used in this case. Sorry, may be chat room better? As it now feels like answering one bigger Q is harder then answering several smaller questions. Needed 20rep is possible as you have good Qs there.